# Is it possible to hide a running program in the notification area?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

A program I use currently shows up in the notification area on the taskbar. I want the program to run, but not to be visible in the notification area in any way.

I know you can hide the area completely but that is not something I want to do. I would like to just hide a single program. Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't that still called the "tray"? Which program are you talking about, specifically?

Comment: a few actually, i have an apple airport program, touchpad, bluetooth, some stupid hp drive program....

Answer (score 1):

It is possible:

Click the arrow, then click **customize**.  Scroll to the program in question (the one you want to hide) **click** the **drop-down** menu, and select "**Hide icon and notifications**"

Welcome to SuperUser

EDIT:  Try going through the program's options or preferences.  Usually there is something there.  What is the name of this program?

EDIT: It should still work.  If the icon is on the taskbar or hidden under the arrow, that is still the place to remove them.

Comment: The question specifically asked for something other than this: "I don't want to move it into the little arrow part but just be gone – not being able to click it or find it there."

Comment: oops.  I'll have to do something about my answer then...

Comment: yeah some programs don't have that option. thats why I asked

Comment: read my latest edit.